# Adding Pagination Control and Zoom by using a Percentage in a text box or dropdown in WPF Document Viewer

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, controls, customization

I have been searching the net for quite sometime now on how to extend the WPF's Document Viewer control but haven't anything.

I would like to add a Paging feature as well as zoom effect through percentage in textbox/dropdown. Is this possible and how?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can't still figure this out guys. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out! I extended the style of document viewer to include pager and combo box for the zoom since its xaml. Then handled textchanged and selected item changed of both controls to manually update the document viewer. documentViewer.GotToPage(n) and documentViewer.Zoom.